# Difference between instance and initialization

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I hope i'm not out of order on my fisrt post here
I'm a triple-oh nooob wanting to get fundamental concepts right

I get what classes are all about, but not so clear on difference between instances and inits ( initialisations )

Can i think of it this way?:

A small building development site has a design approved. (Blueprint) That'll be the class, sure enough

The 'instance' would be one unit bought in from the factory on a truck and craned in

but would the init be when the surveyor comes and pegs out its space 'allocation' on the site ? ( I started in Objective-C before Swift, and have only just looked into swift, you can tell ) or is it something else?

because Swift documentation tels me a 'var' or a 'let' object needs a value assigned, it cant be a nil.
that's strange when I see lots of material with things like

```
var X : Int
let str : String
```

I see no values there, they say they explicitly want to see X = 5 or str ="cotton"

so tat leaves two possible analogies for init() :

```
var X : Int // like the building has the bounds set out, it's just not filling the space?
Var X = 5  // like the building is in place, but still empty and not in habitation
```

not asking for any great discussion, which is the 'more right'? if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite literally, "instantiation" or "initialization" (same thing) is when you CREATE the instance of a class.  So using a similar metaphor, the `Class` is the blueprint for the house, the `Initialization (init)` is when the construction crew builds the house, and the `Instance` is the finished house that you live in.

In your example above, that would be `var x = 5`.  The construction crew just built `x` and set it to `5`.  Now you can do whatever you want with your instance of `x`, like change it to `6`.  Your first example of telling everyone that `x` is going to be an `Int` is what the `Class` is for.

Answer (score 1):

The class is the blue print for your object.  E.G. MyObject contains these variables , x, y and z and has these methods foo1, foo2, foo3.  The instance of a class is a instantiation (creation) of a single object that contains values for x, y and z and can use these methods foo1, foo2, foo3.

The init of a class does any initialization the class needs, usually assigning values to the constructed objects variables, x = 3, y = 4, and z = 5.  Anything that you want done upon construction of the object should be done in the init.

In swift, if you create a variable but don't initialize it with a value, e.g. var x : int, and try to use that variable you will get a compiler error.  The object is instantiated but not initialized.  If you need your variable to contain nil, you must use the optional marker (?),  var x: int? = nil.  Variable x is now of type optional.